# Rails app not loading mp3 file to play in HTML 5 player

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, asset-pipeline, html5-audio

I have an mp3 file saved in my assets/audio folder and want to play it using the html 5 player.  However, when I load my page I always get a 404 not found error for that resource.  Wondering if I am doing this wrong.

In view.html.erb

```
<audio src="app/assets/audio/bensound-acousticbreeze.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" controls>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I have verified multiple times that the full path is correct.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab in your browsers debugger? What's it tell you about the request? Is it requesting the path as your telling it to?

Comment: I did look at the network tab, but it dawned on my to compare the path with the path of some of my assets that were loading and I was able to figure out what the issue is.  Apprently all rails assets get collapsed down into the assets directory, even if they are in sub-directories.  The correct path was just assets/bensound-acousticbreeze.mp3

Comment: Awesome. Good information. You should really be using the built in path providers though, to avoid that kind of thing. This will also do some future-proofing in the case that the asset pipeline changes down the road. Please see my answer for the _better_ way to do it with the `audio_tag`

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:**
Found this while looking up a few things to answer the question. Better than any other solution here is to use the built-in `audio_tag`. This does remove the alternate text option though, so there's that. Still, here's the [doc page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-audio_tag).

---

Have your tried `audio_path` or `asset_path`?

That would look like this:

```
<audio src="<%= audio_path 'audio/bensound-acousticbreeze.mp3'%>" type="audio/mpeg" controls>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

or

```
<audio src="<%= asset_path 'audio/bensound-acousticbreeze.mp3'%>" type="audio/mpeg" controls>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

You **should** simplify by keeping your audio in the `audios` dir as seen in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-audio_path). Then it would just be:

```
audio_path "bensound-acousticbreeze.mp3"
```

All together with the html:

```
<audio src="<%= audio_path 'bensound-acousticbreeze.mp3'%>" type="audio/mpeg" controls>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: I did use the asset_path tag, although the path you mentioned wasn't quite right (it turned out to be assets/bensound-acousticbreeze.mp3 ), I was able to finally get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently all rails assets get collapsed down into the assets directory, even if they are in sub-directories. The correct path was just "assets/bensound-acousticbreeze.mp3."

To anyone having trouble like this, it helped me to compare the path of the missing asset with the one I wanted to load to see what the difference was.